# Solve differential equation $y'+\frac{2(1+\sin x)y}{\cos x}=\frac{2(1-\sin x)(10-x)\sqrt{y}}{x^2(x^2+2x+5)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'+\frac{2(1+\sin x)y}{\cos x}=\frac{2(1-\sin x)(10-x)\sqrt{y}}{x^2(x^2+2x+5)}$

This is Bernoulli's differential equation $y'+p(x)y=q(x)y^ \alpha$ where $$\alpha=\frac{1}{2},p(x)=\frac{2(1+\sin x)}{\cos x},q(x)=\frac{2(1-\sin x)(10-x)}{x^2(x^2+2x+5)}$$

Substitution $$y=z^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}=z^2\Rightarrow 2zz'+\frac{2(1+\sin x)}{\cos x}z^2=\frac{2(1-\sin x)(10-x)}{x^2(x^2+2x+5)}z$$

How to solve this equation?

Comment: Just check [Bernoulli ode](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

So you have:

$$y' + p(x)y = q(x)y^\alpha$$

which can be rewritten as:

$$y'y^{-\alpha} + p(x)y^{1 - \alpha} = q(x)$$

Now we make the substitution:

$$z = y^{1 - \alpha}$$
$$z' = (1 - \alpha)y'y^{-\alpha}$$

and plug in directly to get:

$$\frac{z'}{1 - \alpha} + p(x)z = q(x)$$
$$z' + (1 - \alpha)p(x)z = (1 - \alpha)q(x)$$

which is now a first-order linear differential equation. Notice that we do not have to worry about $\alpha = 1$ because we have to initially assume $\alpha \neq 1$ since that would not classify as a Bernoulli equation. To solve the remaining equation we have to define the integrating factor:

$$\mu = e^{(1 - \alpha)p(x)}$$

which will be used as follows:

$$\mu z' + \mu (1 - \alpha)p(x)z = \mu (1 - \alpha)q(x)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} (\mu z) = \mu (1 - \alpha)q(x)$$
$$d(\mu z) = \mu (1 - \alpha) q(x) dx$$
$$\int d(\mu z) = \int \mu (1 - \alpha) q(x) dx$$
$$\mu z = \int \mu (1 - \alpha) q(x) dx$$
$$z = \frac{1}{\mu} \int \mu (1 - \alpha) q(x) dx$$

With $z$ determined, we can write down the solution for $y$ as follows:

$$y^{1 - \alpha} = z$$
$$y = z^{\frac{1}{1 - \alpha}}$$
$$y = \Bigg[ \frac{1}{\mu} \int \mu (1 - \alpha) q(x) dx \Bigg]^{\frac{1}{1 - \alpha}}$$

Comment: The integral is tricky - do you think it can be solved analytically?

Comment: An excellent question. I honestly did not try the specific functions above, but would bet just by looking at the functions involved that probably not.

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* yields:

$y(x)\to \frac{\left(\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\sin
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)^4 \left(x \left(-2 c_1+2 \log (x)-\log (x(x+2)+5)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)\right)+4\right){}^2}{4 x^2}$

For $c_1 = 1$:

[image]